# Report a Blogspot blog as spam or for malware

Tags: spam-prevention, blogger

How do you report a Blogspot blog for spam? Used to be that there would be a nav bar on all blogs hosted by Blogspot that you could click a "Report this site" button and it would take you to a form to fill out.

But what about the splogs (spam blogs) where they hide or remove that navigation bar? Have seen more than a few of these shady bloggers go about with a design that eliminates this part of the template.

Can you still go to some form and send a note to Google that a certain blog is only there to get you to watch live sports online or some other get fat and/or rich quick scheme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can submit spam, phishing and malware blogs to the form at the bottom of this page for review by Google: https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/42577?hl=en